# VBA Runtime error 1004 Range with double digits

Tags: vba, excel, range, runtime-error

My intent is to select every other cell in a row. My code (I'm sure there's got to be a better way to accomplish this but one step at a time I guess):

```
Range("C" & row & ":C" & row + 1 & ", E" & row & ":E" & row + 1 & ", G" & row & ":G" & row + 1 & ", I" & row & ":I" & row + 1 & ", K" & row & ":K" & row + 1 & ", M" & row & ":M" & row + 1 & ", O" & row & ":O" & row + 1 & ", Q" & row & ":Q" & row + 1 & ", S" & row & ":S" & row + 1 & ", U" & row & ":U" & row + 1 & ", W" & row & ":W" & row + 1 & ", Y" & row & ":Y" & row + 1 & ", AA" & row & ":AA" & row + 1 & ", AC" & row & ":AC" & row + 1 & ", AE" & row & ":AE" & row + 1 & ", AG" & row & ":AG" & row + 1 & ", AI" & row & ":AI" & row + 1 & ", AK" & row & ":AK" & row + 1 & ", AM" & row & ":AM" & row + 1 & ", AO" & row & ":AO" & row + 1 & ", AQ" & row & ":AQ" & row + 1 & ", AS" & row & ":AS" & row + 1 & ", AU" & row & ":AU" & row + 1 & ", AW" & row & ":AW" & row + 1 & ", AY" & row & ":AY" & row + 1 & ", BA" & row & ":BA" & row + 1).Select
```

I am incrementing by 2 to highlight every other row as well. It returns an error (Method 'range' of object' _Global' failed) when `row` is anything over 10. I have been unable to find any answers through Google. Doesn't seem to be a common issue. I'm truly mystified as to why it only works for single digit rows. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: IIR there's a 255 character limit for a text `Range` specification.

Comment: Or take the whole string and paste it in the immediate window like this `?string` to see what is it producing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be much easier to code | read | debug.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("mySheet") 'change as needed

Dim x as Integer
For x = 3 to 53 Step 2 'loop from C to BA skipping 1 column in between

   Dim rngEveryOther as Range
   If rngEveryOther is Nothing
       Set rngEveryOther = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i,x),ws.Cells(i+1,x))
   Else
       Set rngEveryOther = Union(rngEveryOther, ws.Range(ws.Cells(i,x),ws.Cells(i+1,x)))
   End If

Next

rngEveryOther.Select
```

The Union statement will join cells into an existing range (if that is not obvious from the code).

Comment: A little adjustment and it works like a charm! Thank you so much!